# Imcache Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am new to [imcache](https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache). I was looking for the right spring configuration for imcache. I can create the cache but I cannot use the cachebuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a new example on the imcache project about spring configuration. Check it out at [imcache spring configuration example](https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache/blob/master/imcache-examples). Its name is SpringConfigurationExample.java